# Proving that $\operatorname{Null}(A) = \operatorname{Null}(A^TA)$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A$ be an $m×n$ matrix. Prove that $\operatorname{Null}(A) =
>  \operatorname{Null}(A^TA)$. In other words, prove that a vector $x ∈
>  \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfies $Ax = 0$ if and only if $A^TAx = 0$.

For the proof in the backward direction, we can say...
Assume $\exists x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $A^TAx = 0$.

Then:

$$A^TAx = 0$$
$$x^TA^TAx = x^T0$$

$$(Ax)^TAx = 0$$
$$\|Ax\|^2 = 0$$

Why does the last line $\|Ax\|^2 = 0$ imply that $Ax = 0$ and $x \in \operatorname{Null} (A)$?
Is it because the only vector with length 0 is the zero vector?

Comment: Yes. $\|v\|=0$ iff $v=0$ in an inner product space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; non-zero vectors have positive norm. This is the basis of Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=(y_1~y_2~\cdots~y_n)^{\top}$, then $y^{\top}y=y_1^2+y_2^2+\cdots+y_n^2$. So $y^{\top}y=0$ implies $y_1=y_2=\cdots=y_n=0$, or that $y=\bf{0}$